# How to Build spark to run on existing Hadoop 2.6 Cluster from CDH

Tags: apache-spark, cloudera-cdh

I have an existing Hadoop cluster with version hadoop version `Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.4.2`. I have an existing Spark (version 1.5.1) running on that cluster. However, I want to use Spark 2.0 / Spark 2.1 with some code modifications.

**Update**

I have found out from [cloudera forums](http://community.cloudera.com/t5/Advanced-Analytics-Apache-Spark/Multiple-Spark-version-on-the-same-cluster/m-p/39921#M1607) that in theory, I could just download Spark-2.0 (+ Hadoop-2.6), changed `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` on `conf/spark-env.sh` and do something like

```
./bin/spark-shell --master yarn
```

and basically, I will have Spark-2.0 running on my cluster. However, it still doesn't work. I'm running out of potential solutions that's why I came here.

Comment: Is this a CM-managed cluster? If so, a new Spark 2.0 parcel (beta) is available now.

Answer (score 0):

A Spark 2.0 Beta will be available from Cloudera soon. You'll be able to easily install it on Cloudera Manager-managed clusters via a parcel.